# Android: How Can I save my arraylist to a file from a generic class

Tags: java, android, arraylist, writetofile

How Can I save my arraylist to a file from a generic class? I need to store my arraylist directly from a singleton. So I can't get the Context because it is not an activity

Comment: `Application` and `Service` are `Context` too ... without Context you can't do this ...

Comment: How can I get a generic Context to pass to my Manager?

Comment: make `void save(Context ctx)` in your Manager and pass there Activity or Service (it depends where you call it) ... i think that using singletons in Android app it is not a good choice